# can't change upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, wamp

i have upload form at laravel 5 but i can't upload file size larger than 2M

use WAMP,window 10, and all local

i did this but nothing change:

change php.ini from "wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25" and "wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10"

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

change .htaccess from my project

```
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
php_value memory_limit 2500M
```

chagne wamp to XAMPP and do all again but still no change.
actually when i edit php.ini and htaccess  everything is correct but in my project still 2M limit???!!!!

my phpinfo()

```
Configuration File  C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini
```

and when i use this code in my project,result is :

```
{{ini_get('upload_max_filesize')}}  2M
{{ini_get('post_max_size')}}        8M
```

and yes.i'm sure edited all php.ini in my wamp folder

and yes i restart my wamp

Comment: I know you said you are sure you modified all php.ini files in your WAMP folder but I just wanted to double check because I don't think the accepted answer is a good one.  There is generally another php.ini file which your webserver is using located at `wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.x.x\bin\php.ini`.  Did you make sure to modify that one as well?  The php.ini under the `php` directory is used in the CLI only for most WAMP installs.

Comment: well i checked all php.ini file but in fact nothing changed. so i just restart computer instead restart Wamp and then it just workd. when i use wordpress only restart wamp would be enough but in that case just needed restart PC . i just don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change it dynamically in your PHP scripts.

Like this :

```
<?php
ini_set('post_max_size', '2000M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2000M');
```

Answer (score 1):

post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are directives you can set to configure your PHP setup, so they don’t depend on the PHP framework you might use.

You can set the values in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini

php.ini example:

```
post_max_size=15M 
upload_max_filesize=15M
```

.htaccess example:

```
php_value post_max_size=15M 
php_value upload_max_filesize=15M
```

httpd.conf example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
  <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_value post_max_size=15M 
      php_value upload_max_filesize=15M
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```